# How to check if props item is undefined?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm retrieving information from an api.  On the feed page, if the redux prop is empty... I want it to prop a "error" message. If not proceed.

However, I keep getting ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

```
props.posts.length === undefined
```

using the above to check if its undefined isn't stopping it from hitting the error.  Obviously, it takes a while to retrieve data from the api as I get
Array length : 0 , 0 , 100.  Which is why I'm assuming I'm getting the error. but then how do I tell it to just check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just check if `props.posts` is defined (or truthy):

```
if(!props.posts){
  // props.posts is falsy here, which won't be the case when it's an array
}
```

Other options include:

[Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to help perform this check. It has good browser support, and create react app supports it by default.

```
props.posts?.length === undefined
```

Logical Operator short circuiting: I.e. if `props.posts` is falsy, then `!props.posts` is truthy, and it would never reach the right side of the `||` operator.

```
!props.posts || props.posts.length === undefined
```